# Merge changes from remote magento repos get aborting

Tags: magento2, git

Today went to to get new changes from the Magento repo in the develop branch.
I'm using phpstorm.

Commands I used

```
git remote add mageblob git@github.com:magento/magento2.git
git fetch mageblob
git checkout dev <= this is my local dev
git merge mageblob/develop
```

Merge process go aborting and suggest me remove files in dev/tests var/.htaccess v.v..
How to fix it. 
p/s: Btw this is best way to pull all code changes from repos? i'm newbie in git

Answer (score 0):

You have changes in local files. If you want to preserve local changes use:

```
git stash save
git merge mageblob/develop
git stash pop
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675841/git-stash-merge-stashed-change-with-current-changes

If you don't need these changes just reset (**be careful all non-committed changes will be lost**):

```
git reset --hard
git merge mageblob/develop
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! which one is better when get latest code from remote repos? merge or pull

Comment: `pull` will perform a `fetch` and additionally `merge` or `rebase` the changes into your local branch depending on the configuration setting `pull.rebase` or `branch.master.rebase`. I use `fetch` and `merge` when I suspect non-fast-forward merge. And I use `pull` if my local code have no difference with same origin tree.